How to pass online images to Gemini model?
I try to use Gemini model to generate descriptions for online images, but failed at the converting Pillow iamge format to vertext ai image format. Running below code encounters this error: AttributeError: 'JpegImageFile' object has no attribute 'data' at the line of image_part = Part.from_image(pil_image).
import requests
from io import BytesIO
from vertexai.generative_models import Part, Image
from PIL import Image as PILImage

image_path = "https://i.natgeofe.com/n/548467d8-c5f1-4551-9f58-6817a8d2c45e/NationalGeographic_2572187_square.jpg" # this link is an example
response = requests.get(image_path)
pil_image= PILImage.open(BytesIO(response.content))
image_part = Part.from_image(pil_image)

vertexai.init(project="project-name", location="region")
model = GenerativeModel(model_name="gemini-1.0-pro-vision-001")

query = "Please describe the image."
response = model.generate_content(
    [image_part, query]
)

I expected there was no error.

The problem is that the Part.from_image() method can't use a Pillow Image directly. You need to change the Pillow Image into a format that the Part class can work with, like a raw image file in bytes.

The following implementation worked for me. Instead of using the PIL library to open the image and passing it to the from_image method, you'll instead want to use from_data method and the value from the bytes object with its mime type to get a response from Gemini.
import requests
from io import BytesIO
from vertexai.generative_models import Part, Image, GenerativeModel

image_path = "https://i.natgeofe.com/n/548467d8-c5f1-4551-9f58-6817a8d2c45e/NationalGeographic_2572187_square.jpg" # this link is an example
response = requests.get(image_path)
im_bytes = BytesIO(response.content)
image_part = Part.from_data(
    im_bytes.getvalue(),
    mime_type='image/jpeg'
)

vertexai.init(project="project-name", location="region") # Don't forget to set these
model = GenerativeModel(model_name="gemini-1.0-pro-vision-001")

query = "Please describe the image."
response = model.generate_content(
    [image_part, query]
)

The final version of the code returns:
candidates {
  content {
    role: "model"
    parts {
      text: "A grey and white tabby cat with striking blue eyes peers curiously at something to the right of the frame. The sharp focus on the feline\'s face and the blurred, vanishing whiskers set against a stark black background give the image a sense of depth and drama.  The cat appears alert and interested, its head slightly turned as if listening intently. \n"
    }
  }
...

Source: Google Cloud Vertex AI Generative Models Part

Google has Image integrated into the Vertex AI SDK this is all you need.
from vertexai.generative_models import GenerativeModel, Part, SafetySetting, Image
image1 = Part.from_image(Image.load_from_file("/image.png"))
